# Where to find database file for iOS tests

Tags: sqldelight

I've set up my tests to the native driver for iOS. However, I've noticed some issues with the iOS database not being fully torn-down between my tests and want to delete the file if possible to give a clean start, but I don't actually know where it is stored.

Where can I find the iOS database file (in particular during tests), or is there an api I'm not aware of that allows me to delete it through SQLDelight?

Answer (score 2):

I found them in Application Support Directory in subdirectory databases

Comment: Elaborating a bit more. I found them under `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/SOME-DEVICE-UUID/data/Library/Application Support/databases`